# Как динамически кастомизировать массив объектов к массиву примитивов

Tags: java, массивы, spring-aop

Я использую для логирование АОП, Spring, log4j. Есть необходимость отображать в виде строки входящие параметры каждого метода, помеченного @Loggable. Ниже приведен код. Если входящим параметром будет массив примитивов, то приходится делать длинную проверку, представленную в методе arrayToString(). Если просто делать приведение (Object[]), то возникает ClassCastomException. Можно ли упростить arrayToString() с помощью generic или еще другим способом? Спасибо

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect
{
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Around("@annotation(logger.Loggable)")
    public Object logMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint)
    {

        if (joinPoint.getArgs() != null)
        {
            Object[] arrayArgs = convertArgsToString(joinPoint.getArgs());
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    private Object[] convertArgsToString(Object[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        {
            if (args[i] != null && args[i].getClass().isArray())
            {
                args[i] = arrayToString(args[i]);
            }
        }
        return args;
    }

    private String arrayToString(Object array){
        String result;
        if (array instanceof boolean[]) {
            result = Arrays.toString((boolean[])array);
        }
        else if (array instanceof byte[]) {
            result = Arrays.toString((byte[])array);
        }
        else if (array instanceof short[]) {
            result = Arrays.toString((short[])array);
        }
        else if (array instanceof char[]) {
            result = Arrays.toString((char[])array);
        }
        else if (array instanceof int[]) {
            result = Arrays.toString((int[])array);
        }
        else if (array instanceof long[]) {
            result = Arrays.toString((long[])array);
        }
        else if (array instanceof float[]) {
            result = Arrays.toString((float[])array);
        }
        else if (array instanceof double[]) {
            result = Arrays.toString((double[])array);
        }
        else {
            result = Arrays.toString((Object[])array);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, в java нельзя преобразовать массив примитивов в массив объектов, поэтому, единственный способ решить вашу проблему без использованя сторонних библиотек описан вами же.

Однако, библиотека [Apache Commons Lang](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3) содержит класс ArrayUtils, в котором, в свою очередь, есть статический метод toString(Object array), который и решает вашу проблему. То есть, используя эту библиотеку, можно переписать код таким образом:

```java
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Around("@annotation(logger.Loggable)")
    public Object logMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {

        if (joinPoint.getArgs() != null) {
            Object[] arrayArgs = convertArgsToString(joinPoint.getArgs());
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    private Object[] convertArgsToString(Object[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            if (args[i] != null && args[i].getClass().isArray()) {
                args[i] = ArrayUtils.toString(args[i]);
            }
        }
        return args;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ